# Printing the mean NPP value from MODIS imagery in a specific region?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am getting started with Google Earth Engine, trying to do something simple: calculate the mean Net Primary Productivity in a region that is defined by a polygon. NPP values are taken from the MODIS satellite data. I can get the MODIS data, select the NPP band, filter the area by a polygon, but I am unable to do the simple act of printing out the mean value of NPP in the region.

Instead of printing out single numeric value (the mean), the Console prints out YAML metadata for an Image (with id, crs, crs_transform, data_type and so forth). I don't want the damn image metadata, just a simple, single, computed value. My JavaScript code is below:

```
//Get the MODIS data
var mod_npp = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/055/MOD17A3');
var mod_npp_only = mod_npp.select(['Npp']);


//Define the area of interest 
var lmnp_terr = 
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[35.626418548030756, -3.3142503419625107],
          [35.626418548030756, -3.9090722349373133],
          [36.049392180843256, -3.9090722349373133],
          [36.049392180843256, -3.3142503419625107]]], null, false);

//Filter the MODIS data to the area of interest
var lmnp_npp = mod_npp_only.filterBounds(lmnp_terr);

// (try to) calculate the mean NPP in the filtered area 
var mean_npp_lmnp = lmnp_npp.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());

// (try to) print out a single integer value of mean NPP in the polygon. This fails.
print(mean_npp_lmnp);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you have is that you have created a collection.

```
//Get the MODIS data
var mod_npp = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/055/MOD17A3');
var mod_npp_only = mod_npp.select(['Npp']);
```

These lines select the `Npp` band from the collection.  (you still have a collection)

When you use the `.filterBounds()` you apply that to a geographical area, but you are still dealing with a collection.

You will need to further filter it to a specific image, for example with `.first()`

Then you can apply the reducer for the geographical region you identified.

```
// (try to) calculate the mean NPP in the filtered area 
var mean_npp_lmnp = lmnp_npp.first().reduceRegion({
                            reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                            geometry: lmnp_terr});


// (try to) print out a single integer value of mean NPP in the polygon. 
print(mean_npp_lmnp);
```

The `reduceRegion()` function takes the region of Interest as a geometry and applies the reducer to that region (in your case `ee.Reducer.mean()`